# Calling Input Types in Code Behind

Tags: c#, html, input

OK, I never use this :

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" />
```

I usually use this :

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

With the last one I am able to call the textbox like so in my code behind :

```
username.Text = "blah blah"
```

But with the first one I am not able to call it by the `id`. Can anyone tell me how I can call the first example `input type` in my code behind?

Comment: Pretty sure this is some form of ASP, likely ASP.NET; you'd likely find more answers with the right question tag. I would've added it for you, but I don't know enough about ASP to know which exact version it is.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `asp:TextBox`? It will essentially generate the above `input` field anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" t....
```

First one you can't call in code behind cause it's not a server side control. You can call only those control in your code behind which are defined as server side control with `runat` property.

To call the first one in your code behind add the `runat="server"` property like

```
<input type="text" name="username" runat="server" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `runat` property to the `input` and in the code behind you can set input properties in the code behind with input id.

For Eample : you have this textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" runat="server" />
```

and You Can Set text value from code behind:

```
txt1.Value = "my value";
```